# Trouble packaging Python script with PyInstaller: "Failed to load ViGEmClient.dll"

Tags: python

I am facing an issue when packaging my Python script using PyInstaller. The script utilizes the 'vgamepad' library, and while it runs successfully with Python, I encounter the following error when attempting to create a standalone executable with PyInstaller:

```
Failed to load dynlib/dll 'C:\Users\google\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI150362\vgamepad\win\vigem\client\x64\ViGEmClient.dll'.
Most likely, this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
```

Contrary to the common advice, I have not been able to locate the 'ViGEmClient.dll' file in my project directory or elsewhere on my system.

**Relevant Code:**

```
try:
    import vgamepad
except Exception as e:
    input(e)
```

**Environment:**

- Operating System: Windows 10
- Python Version: 3.12.0
- PyInstaller Version: 6.3.0
- vgamepad Version: 0.1.0

I have been unable to find the 'ViGEmClient.dll' file as suggested in similar cases. Any guidance on locating or resolving this dependency issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried finding in your Python path, the folder containing your python.exe? I'm able to locate the .dll file in `Lib\site-packages\vgamepad\win\vigem\client\x64` from my Python path.

Comment: Yes and i don't find it too.

Comment: In this case, you can download the missing dll the from [the vgamepad's repo](https://github.com/yannbouteiller/vgamepad/tree/main/vgamepad/win/vigem/client/x64).

Comment: Done! But still not working.

Comment: What does your pyinstaller command look like?

Comment: Even when my code is only importing vgamepad i'm getting this error. My pyinstaller command is simple: `pyinstaller my_script.py --onefile`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment section, you can download the missing `.dll` the from the [vgamepad's Github repo](https://github.com/yannbouteiller/vgamepad/tree/main/vgamepad/win/vigem/client/x64).

> Even when my code is only importing vgamepad i'm getting this error. My pyinstaller command is simple: `pyinstaller my_script.py --onefile`

It's because PyInstaller doesn't copy the missing .dll file to the standalone executable, so the executable can't find that .dll file which `vgamepad` requires. You need to tell PyInstaller to copy your .dll file:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-binary "ViGEmClient.dll:vgamepad\win\vigem\client\x64" my_script.py
```

In this example, `ViGEmClient.dll` is in the same folder as my_script.py, your path may vary.

**EDIT**: I have just found another way to achieve this, just in case the `--add-binary` didn't work, that's to use the `--collect-binaries` parameter instead:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --collect-binaries=vgamepad my_script.py
```